# net::scp copy/overwriting folder

Tags: ruby, ssh, scp

Say you copy folder `f_1` from your local machine to target machine `m_1` into the `/tmp` directory as `mf_1`.

```
console:
[root@m_1 tmp] ls -a | grep mf_1 # => doesn't exist

irb:
options = {recursive: true}
Net::SCP.upload!(host, user, '~/f_1', '/tmp/mf_1', options)

console:
[root@m_1 tmp] ls -a | grep mf_1 # => folder exists, everything is fine

# but then, if you try to overwrite the existing folder...
irb:
Net::SCP.upload!(host, user, '~/f_1', '/tmp/mf_1', options)

console:
[root@m_1 tmp] ls -a | grep mf_1 # => folder exists
[root@m_1 tmp] cd mf_1
[root@m_1 m_f1] ls # => f_1 => /tmp/mf_1/f_1
```

So, instead of `mf_1` being overwritten folder was copied inside of `/tmp/mf_1`, resulting in `/tmp/mf_1/f_1`.

The question is pretty simple, how to preserve the behavior so it's consistent and calling

```
Net::SCP.upload!(host, user, '~/f_1', '/tmp/mf_1', options)
```

twice in a row would act the same way both when folder exists and doesn't?

Comment: You should consider using SFTP rather than SCP if you can.

Comment: @Kenster, could you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a dot, if source is a dir.
This is not ideal, here's an example:

```
options = {recursive: true}

# target /tmp/mf_1 doesn't exist
Net::SCP.upload!(host, user, '~/f_1/.', '/tmp/mf_1', options)
# target /tmp/mf_1 has been created

# second time
Net::SCP.upload!(host, user, '~/f_1/.', '/tmp/mf_1', options)
# target /tmp/mf_1 has been overwritten
# not dir, but files in it, which is what we usually want
```

Comment: ```Net::SCP.upload!``` it doesn't create create `/tmp/mf_1` folder